# Garbage from decrypted base64 string

Tags: node.js, qt, rsa, crypto++

A Qt client generates a RSA key pair, then sends a json string to a Nodejs server, containing a RSA public key and a text to encrypt.
The NodeJs server is sending back a base64 string containing the text encrypted (using node-rsa) with the RSA public key provided by the client.

My decrypt function on the client side is this:

```
QString Crypto::decrypt(QString b64msg)
{
    //decode the base64 string
    std::string decoded;
    CryptoPP::StringSource ss(b64msg.toStdString(), true,
                           new CryptoPP::Base64Decoder(
                               new CryptoPP::StringSink(decoded)));

    //create a CryptoPP::Integer out of the decoded string
    CryptoPP::Integer encrypted((const byte *)decoded.data(), decoded.size());

    //decrypt using the private key
    CryptoPP::Integer r = privKey.CalculateInverse(rng, encrypted);
    size_t req = r.MinEncodedSize();
    std::string recovered;
    recovered.resize(req);
    r.Encode((byte *)recovered.data(), recovered.size());
    std::cout << "Recovered: " << recovered << std::endl;

    return QString::fromStdString(recovered);
}
```

I just get garbage out of the decrypt function. I think I'm doing everything fine, what am I missing?

EDIT
here's a more detailed iteration:

the client generated the following keypair:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGdMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GLADCBhwKBgQDCe3LEnSuvjc9sERk5JJTnThaB
nTPbQSiSr6fi2pOyREKkOyAGR1DdW1ND96reWkDIrnKE7jw7sTXs/BTKALlXpFdF
1V7FRfiHlB3gRsJYpRzo3OdoXgS/KG/7W9N9H13t+vmi7HSC2EMiqFrpuSJjJm52
MjBW8+wmDMDMmpb0bQIBEQ==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Then the client sends a json request to the NodeJs server. The request is in the form

```
{"command": "encrypt","phrase":"TestString","pubkey":<PEM public key>}
```

This is the code snippet on the NodeJs side:

```
[...]
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
var NodeRSA = require('node-rsa');
[...]
var TCP_PORT = 8081;
var wss = new WebSocketServer({port: TCP_PORT});

wss.on('connection', function connection(socket) {
    socket.on('message', function (data) {
        var request;
        try {
            request = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log("Request:");
            console.log(data);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("Error parsing message: " + e);
            socket.send("json or gtfo");
            return;
        }
        switch (request.command) {
            case "encrypt":
                console.log("phrase: " + request.phrase);
                console.log("pubkey: " + request.pubkey);
                var keypu = new NodeRSA(request.pubkey);
                var resultB64 = keypu.encrypt(request.phrase, "base64", 'utf8');
                socket.send(resultB64);
                [...]
```

The "resultB64" in this iteration is

```
wBuWpfelCB9yIOUQ6ZMPMCPJvn+NYfgjywh4Ye7ybYvNqJdf05yqgrqudkwAJT9+VaIIS/KE/38WvGxiTTY5qZm+rlRrY5OBDZzKRRH4iEKp1NFRJXhh9ZtHPRM/2JfVMUYSFdIgyP3CojIUz2dyLfZu7XLn3RYXI29EJEyHxKM=
```

As a matter of fact, if I pass the private key too and try to decrypt on the server side, the decryption is successful, so I assume the Nodejs side it fine.

@Kombinator: i noted that on the client side I obtain the exact same (garbage)  result if I substitute this:

```
std::string decoded;
CryptoPP::StringSource ss(b64msg.toStdString(), true,
                       new CryptoPP::Base64Decoder(
                           new CryptoPP::StringSink(decoded)));
```

with its QByteArray equivalent:

```
std::string decoded;
QByteArray fromB64 = QByteArray::fromBase64(b64msg.toLatin1());
decoded = fromB64.toStdString();
```

Comment: Can this be text coding/encoding issue? Is `b64msg` correct? Is `decoded` correct after `toStdString`? Do `fromStdString` encode correctly?

Comment: The [Base64 decoding looks good](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Base64Decoder). We need to see the encryption function. Also, that's an unusual use of RSA. Also see [RSA Cryptography](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/RSA_Cryptography) and [RSA Encryption](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/RSA_Encryption_Schemes) on the Crypto++ wiki.

Comment: I edited the question to include more details.

Comment: Node.JS is probably encrypting with RSA and PKCS 1.5 padding. Its not compatible with the [raw RSA encryption](http://cryptopp.com/wiki/Raw_RSA). You probably want to avoid PKCS 1.5 padding, and want OAEP padding on both sides. Also, be sure the plain text is small enough to be encrypted without losing data.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use unit test for this problem. First brake down the complex  method with inline by value calls. 
Use std:string only with test values.  On the other side you shoud use QByteArray for base64 stuff.